# What is the name of a Steiner Quadruple System allowing multisets?

Tags: combinatorics, terminology, combinatorial-designs

A Steiner Quadruple System is a collection $\mathcal{C}$ of subsets of 4 elements of a set $U$ such that every three element subset of $U$ lies in exactly one member of $\mathcal{C}$.

Is there a name for the following (slight) generalization:

$\mathcal{C}$ is a collection of *multisets* of cardinality 4, with elements from $U$ (e.g. $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ might be in $\mathcal{C}$ but so might $\{1, 1, 2, 5\}$) such that every 3-element multiset with elements from $U$ is contained in exactly one member of $\mathcal{C}$?

(Of course the same question can be asked about the similar generalization of the more famous Steiner Triple Systems, it just so happened that I needed the word in the Quadruple System case. But if a notation has been introduced in the Triple System Case I am happy to adopt it!)

Comment: How is "containment" defined when dealing with multisets? In particular, is $\{1, 1, 2\}$ a "sub-multiset" of $\{1, 2, 3\}$?

Comment: Thanks for the question! No in my view containment counts the multiplicity so $\{1, 1, 2\}$ is a subset of $\{1, 1, 2, 3\}$ but not of $\{1, 2, 3\}$. (I don't know what is customary in multi-set theory, but this is what I intended in the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [this paper](http://www.mat.ucm.es/serv/revmat/vol21-1/vol21-1g.pdf) - it contains some interesting stuff. The collections you are looking into are called "Extended Steiner Quadruple Systems" there.